# How do I serialize an javascript array into html attribute and fetch it back with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr=[...];

var html = '<input attr="' + serialize(arr) + '">';
```

I can't simply `join(' ')` the `arr` as there may be white space or other special characters.

How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `.data`, using which you can store any data on a DOM element.

```
var html = $("<input>");
html.data("something", arr);
```

Then you can append it somewhere using the insertion methods like `.append`.

Fetch the data again with:

```
var arr = html.data("something");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UKRcs/

---

An alternative would be using JSON to convert things into a string and setting that as an attribute:

```
var html = $("<input>").attr("data-something", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

And the other way round:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(html.attr("data-something"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UKRcs/1/

Comment: @Je Rog: Can't you use the jQuery functions? If you can, you really ought to, because `.data` is by far the most convenient way of storing data on an element.

Comment: Lots of other code requires to generate html string, so I have to make it compatible with those...

Comment: @Je Rog: That's trickier but certainly possible - see my edit please.

Comment: Do you mean `'<input attr="' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '" />'`? This may break DOM because of `'` and `"`...

Comment: @Je Rog: Yes, if you really want a direct string that's the way to for arrays. (Keep in mind that objects would have `"` around their keys so that would break up with the attribute `"`.)

Comment: Is there some other way that will make sure not breaking the DOM?

Comment: @Je Rog: You could make your own (de)serialization format, but it would become tricky. What you could also do is replacing all `"` from the JSON with another character not to break the DOM, and replace them back when deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the .data() method. This allows you to attach arbitrary objects to DOM elements.

http://api.jquery.com/data/